# Failing at constructing an instance of kendo.data.DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a basic problem which prevents me from developing a custom plugin based on KendoGrid. When I do this:

```
var ds = kendo.data.DataSource.create({
    data: [
        { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" }
    ]
});
```

then `ds.view()` returns an empty array. Same with an alternative constructor: `new kendo.data.DataSource({})`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not available because the `view()` method "...should be used within the `change` event handler or the `fetch` method.".

Your code should look something like this.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith" },
    { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" }
  ]
});
ds.fetch(function() {
  var view = ds.view();
  console.log(view[0].FirstName); // displays "Joe"
});
```

View the documentation for the view method [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-view).

Comment: My point was actually not the `.view()` method. The same happens when I use `.data()` method. I do not understand why - when I inspect my custom instance through `$('#mygrid').data('kendoMyGrid').dataSource` - I can see the columns as passed to the instance, but can see no data...

Comment: the only thing wrong I see with you code snippet is 'kendoMyGrid'. the data element you should be accessing is 'kendoGrid'. This plnkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/mGgluN2WJnZLypN4GwQ5) shows an example of access the grid data.

Comment: That; s an intrinsic feature of extending a Kendo widget. When you provide a name 'MyWidget' the instance is available from DOM as 'kendoMyWidget'. The thing I don't understand is why the underlying dataSource columns are respected, while data is not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you provide an example.